# How to get cmd output in qt?

Tags: qt

How  to get cmd output in qt ?

I used the below code to get cmd output with qt.

```
QProcess pShell;

pShell.start("java");
pShell.waitForFinished();
qWarning() << pShell.readAllStandardOutput();
```

But , the above code not worked .

Comment: What output do you expect?  Does it start successfully?  Is any data available via `pShell.readAllStandardError()`?  What do you see if you just type `java` at a command prompt?